# Mongo `touch` Command Unexpected Results

Tags: mongodb

With a **11 GB** working set (`db.records.totalSize()`), I ran the `touch` command in order to get Mongo to use as much memory as possible on my 16-GB RAM box. Before running touch, the `serverStatus` command showed that Mongo's `mem.resident` equaled **5800** (roughly 6 GB RAM).

```
db.runCommand({ touch: "records", data: true, index: true })
    { "ok" : 1 }
```

But, after running touch, Mongo's using roughly the same amount of RAM.

```
    "mem" : {
            "bits" : 64,
            "resident" : 5821, /* only a 21 MB increase */
            "virtual" : 29010,
            "supported" : true,
            "mapped" : 14362,
            "mappedWithJournal" : 28724
    },
```

Why did the `touch` command hardly increase how much RAM Mongo uses (mem.resident)?

Answer (score 1):

The way that MongoDB db.serverStatus() command reports resident memory is by counting how many pages in physical RAM were actually accessed by mongod process.

This means that while your collection and indexes were read into RAM they won't show up in "res" value until you start actually querying against it.

You can verify that the data was read into RAM (if it was definitely cold before) just by seeing how much RAM mongod process has (not *virtual* memory).